# stderr redirection in subshell changes output of tput

Tags: bash, unix, shell, ncurses

So I'm working on a script and found some odd behaviour. I'm sure there is a logical explanation why the output of the 4<sup>th</sup> and 6<sup>th</sup> command line is different than in the other cases, but I fail to find it.

```
1 $ tput cols
128

2 $ tput cols 2>/dev/null
128

3 $ echo $(tput cols)
128

4 $ echo $(tput cols 2>/dev/null)
80

5 $ (tput cols >/tmp/cols.txt); cat /tmp/cols.txt
128

6 $ (tput cols &>/tmp/cols.txt); cat /tmp/cols.txt
80

7 $ echo $(tput cols 2>/dev/null; echo $COLUMNS; tput cols)
80 128 128
```

Why does stderr redirection change the output of tput in a subshell?

Ultimately I want to do something like this in my script to make it work on systems where tput/ncurses isn't available:

```
cols=$(tput cols 2>/dev/null || echo $COLUMNS)
```

---

The example above was created with Bash 4.3.46(1)-release and ncurses 6.0.20150627

Comment: I don't have this on my rapsberry, however, number of column might be different when output is non interactive (like a file or /dev/null )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `strace`, this happens because `tput` only tries to read tty settings from its stdout and stderr (fd 1 & 2). Since you've explicitly redirected stderr, and the `$( )` also redirects stdout, tput gives up.

The best fix would be to patch tput to also check *stdin* for presence of a tty; however, you could also just remove the `2>/dev/null` redirect, since `tput cols` never outputs any error messages anyway. (And if it did output some error messages, it's best to pay attention to them.)

Comment: Yes, that might be it. I need to suppress the error in case tput isn't available. As a workaround I'm doing this:

    if tput cols &>/dev/null; then
        cols=$(tput cols)
    else
        cols=$COLUMNS
    fi